# Is there a way to bulk insert into Amazon Aurora RDS directly from Amazon S3 tab delimited files in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I am currently using Amazon Redshift to store aggregated data from the 50 - 100 GB  (ie. millions of rows) of tab delimited files that are pushed to a bucket in Amazon S3 every day.

Redshift makes this easy by providing a `copy` command which can be targeted directly to an S3 bucket to bulk load the data.

I would like to use Amazon Aurora RDS for this same purpose. Documentation on Aurora is thin, at best, right now. Is there a way to bulk load directly from S3 into Aurora?

As far as I can tell, MySql's `LOAD DATA INFILE` requires a path to the file on disk, which I suppose I can work around by downloading the tsv to an AWS instance and running the command from there, though that isn't ideal.

I've also attempted to read the tsv into memory and construct multiple `insert` statements. This is obviously slow and clunky.

Ideas?

**UPDATE 11/2016:**

As of Aurora version 1.8 you can now use the following commands to bulk load S3 data:

`LOAD DATA FROM S3`

or

`LOAD XML FROM S3`

[Aurora Load From S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html)

---

**UPDATE 7/2018:**

Updated AWS Documentation link. Shoutout to Mark Holmes for catching that.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use AWS Data Pipeline. There is even a template for loading data from S3 to RDS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html

Answer (score 4):

FYI as of July 2018 the "Aurora Load From S3" link above just goes to the user guide main page.  This link goes directly to the topic which describes IAM roles and other prerequisites for security before LOAD FROM S3 will succeeed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html

This post comes up near the top of my search results, so I wanted to update this with current info.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll update the link in my question.

Comment: It looks like it does not support encryption.